# How to assert with current date?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, automated-tests, rest-assured

Trying to assert an object and that object needs to be equal to the local date on whichever date the test is run.

I have the following code:

```
import java.util.Date; 

public class {


    float validateMetDate = S55.jsonPath().getFloat("details.ref"); 
    Assert.assertEquals(validateMetDate, crDate.getDate()); 

}
```

The library above I am trying to use only works with day of the week looks like or I am missing something.

Comment: The Java class that represents a day, month and year is `java.time.LocalDate`.  I assume that's what you mean by "needs to be equal to the local date".  But you're comparing a `float` value with a value whose type is unclear from the code above.  I would suggest you throw away `java.util.Date` (which has been obsolete for about 10 years, and isn't the right kind of thing for your requirement) and deal only with `java.time.LocalDate`.

Comment: Can you show the sample payload that you're trying to process?

Comment: How exactly does your `float` represent a moment or a date?

Comment: Do you understand that `java.util.Date` is not actually a date, it is a date with time of day as seen with an offset from UTC of zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalDate.now worked for me. Thanks all for the help.